# AsyncTask ProgressDialog stopped, after callback

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask

this my task:

```
public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    // callback
    private Activity activity;
    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback;

    private AppUtils appUtils;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String object;



    public GetTask(Activity act){
        this.activity = act;
        this.callback = (AsyncTaskCompleteListener)act;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        dialog.setTitle("Load...");
        dialog.setMessage("Data...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                cancel(false);

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {

        String link = url[0];
        object = AppUtils.cutStringAfter(link); 
        link = AppUtils.cutStringBefore(link); 
        return AppUtils.getJSONData(link);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        if (null != dialog && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.onTaskComplete(result, object);

    }

     @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            if (this.dialog != null) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
}
```

onTaskComplete call other procedure for parse data:

```
    @Override
public void onTaskComplete(JSONObject result, String object) {
    try {
        setDBDATA(result, object);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Dialog dismissed after complete procedure setDBDATA(result, object);, while works setDBDATA, ProgressDialog freezes.

How close ProgressDialog before callback procedure, or prevent freeze him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in opPostExecute() set an onDismissListener() on your ProgressDialog and call the call back method from onDismiss()

Something like this:-

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        callback.onTaskComplete(result, object);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, ProgressDialog is closed. I try setDBDATA incert in other AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

If setDBDATA will take long time, then move it to doInBackground.

Comment: I don't think so. When the SetDBData is called, the progress should have been dismissed already.

Comment: @buptcoder it's not important whether the dialog has been dismissed, call method last for long in UI thread is not recommended.

Comment: I totally agree with you about not handling the data in UI thread. I just want to say xck's problem is not caused by SetDBData.